# Change PHP content depending on screen res?

Tags: php, wordpress, hide, screen-resolution

I'm try to make a simple site.
I want to make that if you have a resolution that is smaller than 481 it will show X, while if your res is bigger, it will show Y.
I tried the following: (in the style)

```
                @media screen and (min-width:482px)
            {
            p.troll { display: block; }
            p.troll2 { display: none; }
            }

            media screen and (max-width:482px)
            {
            p.troll { display: none; }
            p.troll2 { display: block; }
            }
```

and the following in the php page itself:

```
                <p class="troll" >

                <?php bones_main_nav(); // Adjust using Menus in Wordpress Admin ?>

                <?php
                if (current_user_can('level_10')) : ?>

                <div class="adminstuff">
                <a href="/dynmap"></a>
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ); ?>
            </p>

            <p class="troll2">
            i'm on my mobile
            </p>
```

yet it shows both content that are in "troll" and "troll2" in a device that has a small resolution, how can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you missing the "@" sign from the second media query in the real code, or is that just a copy & paste error?

Comment: Just my bad on C&P, it doesnt work even when i fixed that...

Comment: Seems like PHP ignores that display:none.
Cuz whenever I do the same thing, but without any php tags, it works just fine.
How can I fix that? :P

Comment: You should do this responsive design entirely in CSS. PHP itself cannot ignore CSS. PHP is serverside and CSS is clientside.

Comment: How can I display those PHP elements in css? :(
It's elements from Wordpress

Comment: NVM thanks alot pals :P
I figured I can find the resolution using PHP and JS, and then everything went smooth.